# Different Results From Same Table AND Adding Results from Multiple Queries

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working from 2 tables (Table_1, Table_2) and looking for three items within each Table (count App Count, count Apps Approved, count Apps Declined) that all use the same data item APPNUM. I want to query this data from each of the two tables and add the two results together and have each date only listed once.

For App Count Im looking for where DTENTERED between a specific date range (i.e. 12-01-2015 to 12-31-2015)
For Apps Approved and Apps Declined Im looking for where DT_DECISIONED is between that same date range (12-01-2015 to 12-31-2015) but was not necessarily entered in the DTENTERED range. Im assuming I need to do joins within each table for the separate items then union the two tables together.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Teradata? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Teradata is the system that I'm using.

Comment: Without more details it's hard to tell, but you probably need conditional aggregation like `SUM(CASE WHEN DTENTERED BETWEEN ... AND ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`